# Should implicit conversion work in the context of a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, non-type

To be more explicit, should a compiler treat a `true_type` value as `true` in the first argument of `enable_if`, because `true_type` is really `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`, and `integral_constant` defines the type conversion function `operator value_type`?

The following is the simplest test code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<T>{}>
test(T)
{
}

int main()
{
    test(true);
}
```

It is accepted by GCC and Clang, but rejected by MSVC (up to Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.1).

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<(std::is_pod<T>{})>` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is well-formed, [converted constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression) should be considered for [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments).

> The template argument that can be used with a non-type template parameter can be any [converted constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) of the type of the template parameter.
>
> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression
>   [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) to type `T`, where the converted expression is a
>   constant expression, and the implicit conversion sequence contains
>   only:
>
> - `constexpr` user-defined conversions (so a class can be used where integral type is expected)

The conversion operator of [`std::is_pod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) inherited from [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) is `constexpr` user-defined conversions, then the converted `bool` from `std::is_pod` is converted constant expression and could be applied.

---

<sup>As the workaround (I suppose you've realized) you can use `std::is_pod_v<T>` (since C++17) or `std::is_pod_v<T>::value` instead.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I know the workaround. I just wonder whether this is an MSVC bug or not.

Comment: @YongweiWu I think it is, especially when both gcc and clang say yes.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the more general question, yes it should be accepted. MSVC defaults to C++14, so I'll be basing the answer on that standard.

> **[temp.arg.nontype]**
>
> 1 A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of:
>
> [1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg#nontype-1.1) - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration
>   type, a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of
>   the template-parameter; or
>
> **[expr.const]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.const#3) An integral constant expression is an expression of integral or
>   unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where
>   the converted expression is a core constant expression. A converted
>   constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted
>   to a prvalue of type T, where the converted expression is a core
>   constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>   user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions ([conv.lval]),
>   integral promotions ([conv.prom]), and integral conversions
>   ([conv.integral]) other than narrowing conversions ([dcl.init.list]).

Since `integral_constant` supports a `constexpr operator T()` and this user defined conversion may appear in a converted constant expression, your code is perfectly valid. What MSVC seems to get hung up on is its parsing. For when I tried your example, it spat [this out](https://godbolt.org/z/skMKKP)

> ```
> <source>(4): error C2059: syntax error: '<end Parse>'
>
> <source>(4): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
>
> <source>(4): error C2143: syntax error: missing '>' before ';'
>
> <source>(4): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>
> <source>(4): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
>
> <source>(4): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> <source>(4): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>
> <source>(4): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
>
> <source>(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
>
> <source>(6): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
>
> <source>(11): error C3861: 'test': identifier not found
> ```

Microsoft's handling of templates is historically different to GCC's or Clang's, and that could account for this problem in parsing.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention it, but I really specified `cl /EHsc /std:c++17 test.cpp` on the command line.

Comment: @YongweiWu - Makes little difference. C++17 added *more* possible constant expressions. So what was valid in C++14 is still a valid constant expression in C++17.